# dagre-d3- make the long text to fit inside node

Tags: javascript, dagre-d3, dagre

In the setNode we can specify the html as well. if i mention width and height, and if it a long text, it is moving out.

```
g.setNode(0, {
    labelType: "html",
    label: '<div style="color: red; width: 90px; height: 30px;">test data overlapping</div>',
    width: 70,
    height: 35
});
```

I tried to give width to the div but it is not working sample [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bbxvhx17/217/)

How can i make the text to fit inside node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `auto` property on width and height like this:

[Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vishal_ash/3981kev6/1/)

> using `auto` the element will automatically adjust its height and width to allow
>   its content to be displayed correctly.

Comment: Yeah, this should work and this is my final solution, is there any possibility to fit text with in the current width and height?

Comment: well if you are going to fix some particular width and height, then after a point text will always get out of node. You could use white-space property like this:  label: '<div style="color: blue; width: 90px; height: 30px; white-space:normal"> ,     it will help changing line. Happy to help.